# IGrouping<int, Keypair> to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I seperated my main dictonary into a group of multiple dictonaries so that I can shoot threads off with the smaller set of dictonaries.

Here is the code that seperates my main Dictonary into multiple smaller ones:

```
int numberOfGroups = 10;
int counter = 0;
var result = offenderWorkload.GroupBy(x => counter++ % numberOfGroups);
```

Now I am having trouble to obtain one dictonary from the set of 10 within the result.

I need to seperate result into 10 different dictonaries and shoot off threads so something like...

```
foreach(var something in result)
{
    Dictionary<String, int> workLoad = (Dictionary<String, int>)something.ToDictionary();
    Console.WriteLine("workload: " + something.Key + " has " + workLoad.Keys.Count);
}
```

So that something is keypair that gets casted to a dictonary and ignoring the int in the Igroup.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think he wants to partition his dictionary so he can load balance the work.  I don't think GroupBy is what you are looking for. If my assumption is correct, have you tried creating your own partition method? Signature will be public static List<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> Partition<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, int maxCountPerPartition);  or public static List<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> Partition<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, int numPartitions);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<String, int> workLoad = something.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Because after group by, each grouping member is not a dictionary, but a collection of KeyValuePair's.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a Group of dictionaries. each dictionary have `n` elements.

```
int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)offenderWorkload.Count/numberOfGroups);

IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, int>> result =
    offenderWorkload.GroupBy(x => counter++/n)
        .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value));
```

Note that if your dictionary have 12 keys and you want to group them in to 5 dictionaries you will get 4 dictionaries instead, each one have 3 keys.

Because `12/5 = 2.4`. you can have 5 dictionaries with 2 keys plus one dictionary with two keys `2*5+0.4*5`. In total 6 dictionaries which is more than maximum number of groups. **Or** better way, by taking its ceiling you will get maximum possible (or less) than amount of specified groups. Here `[2.4] = 3`. in total 4 dictionaries each have 3 keys.

Another example if you want to group 12 into 7 dictionaries you will get 5 dictionaries instead each one have 2 keys. If you group 13 into 3 you will get 3 dictionaries, Two first dictionaries will have 5 keys and Last one have 3 keys.

In order to get maximum `numberOfGroups` that you have specified choose something that `offenderWorkload.Count` can be divided to. for example If you group 12 into 6 you will get 6 dictionaries each one have 2 keys (`12 / 6 = 2`).

```
int numberOfGroups = 10;
int counter = 0;
int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)offenderWorkload.Count/numberOfGroups);

var result =
    offenderWorkload.GroupBy(x => counter++/n)
        .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value));

int i = 0;
foreach (var workLoad in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("workload: " + i++ + " has " + workLoad.Keys.Count);
}
```